# Codeigniter Displaying Information In A View?

Tags: mysql, function, codeigniter-2

I'm extracting two different sets of data from a function in my model (syntax below). I'm trying to display the data my view. I put the variable in var_dump and var_dump is displaying the requested information but I'm having a hard time accessing that information. I'm getting two different sets of error messages as well. They are below. How would I display the information in my view? Thanks everyone.

Site Controller

```
   public function getAllInformation($year,$make,$model)
   {
     if(is_null($year)) return false;
     if(is_null($make)) return false;
     if(is_null($model)) return false;
     $this->load->model('model_data');
     $data['allvehicledata'] = $this->model_data->getJoinInformation($year,$make,$model);
     $this->load->view('view_show_all_averages',$data);
   }
```

Model_data

```
function getJoinInformation($year,$make,$model)
{
 $data['getPrice'] = $this->getPrice($year,$make,$model);
 $data['getOtherPrice'] = $this->getOtherPrice($year,$make,$model);
 return $data;

}


function getPrice($year,$make,$model)
{
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tbl_car_description d');
 $this->db->join('tbl_car_prices p', 'd.id = p.cardescription_id');
 $this->db->where('d.year', $year);
 $this->db->where('d.make', $make);
 $this->db->where('d.model', $model);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
}

function getOtherPrice($year,$make,$model)
{
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('tbl_car_description d');
 $this->db->where('d.year', $year);
 $this->db->where('d.make', $make);
 $this->db->where('d.model', $model);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
}
```

View

```
<?php
var_dump($allvehicledata).'<br>';

//print_r($allvehicledata);
if(isset($allvehicledata) && !is_null($allvehicledata))
{
    echo "Cities of " . $allvehicledata->cardescription_id . "<br />";
    $id = $allvehicledata['getPrice']->id;
    $model = $allvehicledata[0]->model;
    $make = $allvehicledata->make;
    echo "$id".'<br>';
    echo "$make".'<br>';
    echo "$model".'<br>';
    echo $allvehicledata->year;
}

?>
```

Error Messages

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/view_show_all_averages.php

Line Number: 7

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: views/view_show_all_averages.php

Line Number: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you are assigning the result of function **getJoinInformation** to the variable **allvehicledata**. This variable is then assigned to the view.

The function **getJoinInformation** is returning an array with the following

```
$data = array(
  'getPrice' => $this->getPrice($year,$make,$model),
  'getOtherPrice' => $this->getOtherPrice($year,$make,$model)
);
```

So in your view you can access the attributes `getPrice` and `getOtherPrice` in the object `$allvehicledata` like

```
$allvehicledata->getPrice;
$allvehicledata->getOtherPrice;
```

---

In line 7 you try to access the attribute `cardescription_id`, which is not an attribute of the object `$allvehicledata`.
I think this is an attribute which is get from the db query, so you should try to access it `allvehicledata->getPrice->cardescription_id` or `allvehicledata->getOtherPrice->cardescription_id`.

---

In line 9 you try to access some data stored in an array `$model = $allvehicledata[0]->model;`, but `$allvehicledata` is not an array.

Comment: for the help, appreciate it!